# How to define range that could vary in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a copy of one spreadsheet using a (time driven) Google App Script. I found a very useful piece of code here, but my concern is that the range varies frequently (new rows are added). How can I copy the entire spreadsheet no matter if the range changes?. because as you can see in the code below I have defined the range, but when this changes the information out of the defined range will be discarded. What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Here the code I'm using:

```
    function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
      var timestamp = new Date();
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var range = sheet.getRange('sheetName!A1:AO158');
      sheet.setNamedRange('sheetName', range);
      var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('sheetName').getValues(); 
      Logger.log(TestRange); 
      var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID"); 
      DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("FileName:"+ timestamp, destFolder); 
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to copy an entire spreadsheet or just a particular worksheet from existing spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet?

Comment: A particular worksheet. In this vein, I have noticed that this script copy the entire spreadsheet, when I just want to copy just the referred 'sheetName' worksheet.

Comment: sheet.getDataRange() gets the whole sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the range object defined by the first cell of column A and the last cell in column A that contains data, use this code:

```
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
```

The getRange() method has several overloads and can accept numerical values defining the boundaries of the range as well.  More on this here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)

If you need to copy everything, use getDataRange() method.

Comment: Change the line 4 for your suggestion, I'm getting the following error message: (Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number). (line 4, file "Code"), also my worksheet has more than one colum,

Comment: Please take some time to read the documentation and understand how GAS actually works before trying to change someone else's code line by line.  In this line you are getting the instance of the Spreadsheet object       var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  The getRange() method of the Spreadsheet object only supports a1notation and range name as input parameters. You need to reference the Sheet object before before calling the function with 4 numerical parameters - e.g. var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(yourSheetName). You can then call getRange() on a Sheet object

Comment: Btw, you named your first variable 'sheet', but getActiveSpreadsheet()  returns the entire Spreadsheet object scoped to the script. The following line will only work if you have the sheet named  'sheetName'. Because this is boilerplate code taken from the Internet, I suspect you should have put the name of your sheet instead     var range = sheet.getRange('sheetName!A1:AO158');  Please see the code in this example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12YlzLICzz1itwoyfk_pmAsCnGJunoPomS0cxCm_KzjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the getDataRange() method mentioned is my reply is what you should use to get the entire range that contains data, not just the 1st column